# My posts do not appear in my database

Tags: php, mysql, forms

i have the form and php codes below, but my posts do not appear in my database, and this got me confuse as i don't know where the problem is. Please help out. thanks in advance

form codes is

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Insert New Product</title>
<link rel ="stylesheet" href="admin_style.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <table width="600" align="center" border="10">

            <tr>
                <td align="center" bgcolor="yellow" colspan="6">    <h1>Insert New Product Here</h1></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td align="right">Product Name</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="name" size="30"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right">Product Price</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="price" size="30"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right">Product Main Image</td>
                <td><input type="file" name="mainimage"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right">Product Sub Image 1</td>
                <td><input type="file" name="subimage1"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right">Product Sub Image 2</td>
                <td><input type="file" name="subimage2"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right">Product Sub Image 3</td>
                <td><input type="file" name="subimage3"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center" colspan="6"><input type="submit"     name="submit" value="Post Product Now!"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
<?php
include("includes/connect.php");

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$post_name = $_POST['name'];
$post_price = $_POST['price'];
$post_mainimage = $_FILES['mainimage']['name'];
$post_subimage1 = $_FILES['subimage1']['name'];
$post_subimage2 = $_FILES['subimage2']['name'];
$post_subimage3 = $_FILES['subimage3']['name'];
$mainimage_tmp = $_FILES['mainimage']['tmp_name'];
$subimage1_tmp = $_FILES['subimage1']['tmp_name'];
$subimage2_tmp = $_FILES['subimage2']['tmp_name'];
$subimage3_tmp = $_FILES['subimage3']['tmp_name'];


if($post_name=='' or $post_price=='' or $post_mainimage=='' or
$post_subimage1=='' or $post_subimage2=='' or $post_subimage3==''){


echo "<script>alert('any of the fields is empty')</script>";

exit();

}
else {

move_uploaded_file($mainimage_tmp,"images/$post_mainimage");
move_uploaded_file($subimage1_tmp,"images/$post_subimage1");
move_uploaded_file($subimage2_tmp,"images/$post_subimage2");
move_uploaded_file($subimage3_tmp,"images/$post_subimage3");

$insert_query = "insert into posts 
(post_name,post_price,post_mainimage,post_suimage1,
post_subimage2,post_image3) values ('$post_name','$post_price','
$post_mainimage','$post_subimage1','$post_subimage2','$post_subimage3')";

if(mysql_query($insert_query)){

echo "<center><h1>POST SUCCESSFUL!</h1></center>";

}


}



}

?>
```

thanks in advance

Comment: What is there in connect.php?

Comment: Can you be a bit more descriptive?  Are you getting the "POST SUCCESFUL" message? Is it failing before that? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: check this mysql_query($insert_query) or mysql_error() you will find whether query is running or not

Comment: @user3619935 Put `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the beginning of the PHP file to print the error.

Comment: the "connect.php" is used to connect to the database, i don't get any error message whenever i post and i don't get the "POST SUCCESSFUL" either

Comment: @LucasHenrique, i have done that, but still no error is reported and nothing got posted in my database, but the files were moved into the specified folder

Comment: @user3619935 So your problem is with the database. Is there any PRIMARY KEY field. It is also AUTO_INCREMENT?

Comment: i think i got it right now, my database is now being updated but the problem i face now is after my PUBLISH SUCCECCFUL is echoed when i try to refresh the page it re-post the content to my database, any help on this

Comment: @user3619935 The `name` field is `UNIQUE` or not?

Comment: yes, the name field is UNIQUE

Comment: @user3619935 Put as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The initial problem was solved including `PRIMARY KEY` and `AUTO_INCREMENT` field `id` in table.

The next problem:
Not to insert a new record and its field is `post_name` `UNIQUE`, try using [ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).

```
$insert_query = "insert into posts 
(post_name,post_price,post_mainimage,post_suimage1,
post_subimage2,post_image3) values ('$post_name','$post_price','
$post_mainimage','$post_subimage1','$post_subimage2','$post_subimage3') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE post_price = VALUES(post_price), post_mainimage = VALUES(post_mainimage), 
post_suimage1 = VALUES(post_suimage1), post_suimage2 = VALUES(post_suimage2), post_suimage3 = VALUES(post_suimage3)";
```

Comment: Am sorry guys, this is came late, the problem has been solved, am so so grateful @LucasHenrique